# Stop image that is linked to in XHR response from being cached

Tags: javascript, http, caching

I am using XHR to get some HTML. The HTML response contains an img-element, and this image is for some reason cached.

The server serves the image along with the following headers:

```
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; ...
content-type: image/png
date: Mon, 08 Oct 2018 03:41:00 GMT
expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
server: nginx (Ubuntu)
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=30879000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

And XHR is used like this:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
        addToPage(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
};
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xmlHttp.send();
```

Example XHR response:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Stuff</p>
<img src="/captcha-generator">
```

It works as expected when not using XHR. For some reason the image gets cached when it's linked to from within the XHR response.

Why is the image cached, and how do I force the browser to fetch the new image?

I can of course append a unique parameters to break the cache,(eg. `/captcha-generator?r={random-string}` but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Have you tried a few browsers?

Comment: browser-caching is in built for  a reason, if you want to prevent it you're pretty much only limited to queryString on the end. However if you only want it to fetch it when the image changes i would suggest adding a queryString with your applications version number

Comment: From the response header, it doesn't seem like nginx is caching the asset. So I'd assume this is cached by browser. If that's that, then I don't see any other ways than appending the `url`.

Comment: Try to add Max-age=0

Comment: I don't see any other way either, that's why I'm asking. There sure must be a good explanation to why/how the image is cached when the browser is clearly told not to cache the image, and why it is only happening when the linking elm is part of an XHR response.

Answer (score -1):

In case of Development mode it is happing .So Incase of google crome go to right top
corner click on costomize and control google crome .then open with New inconginto window
for development mode